# Wordpress DIVI theme - can't add image (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined)

Tags: wordpress, typeerror

I'm having hard time understanding what happened. Everything worked flawlessly.
When i try to add or replace image using DIVI visual builder, nothing is happening on click.
This is what i found in console:
[image]

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Function.v.template (underscore.min.js?ver=1.8.3:1)
    at i.template (wp-util.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at i.render (wp-backbone.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at i.attach (media-views.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at i.open (media-views.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at i.<computed> [as open] (media-views.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1)
    at t._onClick (bundle.modals.c075dc5f.js:18)
    at Object.Gg (react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:155)
    at Fg (react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:13)
    at Ig (react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:13)
v.template @ underscore.min.js?ver=1.8.3:1
(anonymous) @ wp-util.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1
render @ wp-backbone.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1
attach @ media-views.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1
open @ media-views.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1
i.<computed> @ media-views.min.js?ver=5.3.2:1
_onClick @ bundle.modals.c075dc5f.js:18
Gg @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:155
Fg @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:13
Ig @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:13
be @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:15
Jg @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:156
Ic @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:15
Kc @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:16
hh @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:39
mg @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:149
se @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:23
Yb @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:40
og @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:150
Te @ react-dom.production.min.js?ver=16.7.0:40
```

Things i try and did not helped me:

- clearing cache
- changing browsers
- disabled divi's js and css minify feature
- rollbacking divi to older version
- changing php version (7.3 actual version)

Running on newest version of wordpress v5.3.2.
I'm running out of options. Any suggestion will help.
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, i've got the same issue, did you figure out anything? I think it is a plugin comflicting
EDIT: For me it was the plugin "popup builder"

Comment: Nope, I tried everything. I was forced to do all over.

Comment: Same issue, glad I'm not the only one. @ThomasNL wouldn't running Divi in safe mode resolve this?

Comment: In our case, we uploaded the theme to the latest version of Divi and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note, when I had this issue it was eventually tracked down to some improperly formatted javascript code in the global footer.